# Usage of "make it" in this context

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Consider the following sentence . My boss (say Mr X) wrote this to me in an email and before this paragraph he actually gave a list of items that I need to work on :

> We will have a Webex meeting at 9:00 AM on Friday with Y to review
>   these items.  Please confirm that you can make it.

Is he saying that I should be done with those items before 9:00 AM on Friday and then have the meeting with Y or is he just asking me to confirm my availablitiy for that meeting ?

Comment: Dictionaries hold the answer to this sort of question.

Comment: Ask your boss. He will tell you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that context "You can make it" means "You will manage to attend at the meeting".

"To make it" is often used in an informal context to mean "to manage to arrive at a place or go to an event", for instance you may say:

> I made it to the cinema just before the movie started.
>
> My parents invited us for dinner Saturday night, can you make it ?